# ArgumentError: No key column found Unstack Error?

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

I have a df like below,

Sample Input:

```
4×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ col1   │ col2  │
│     │ String │ Int64 │
├─────┼────────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ l1     │ 1     │
│ 2   │ l2     │ 2     │
│ 3   │ l1     │ 3     │
│ 4   │ l2     │ 4     │
```

I want to transform the above df to like below,

Expected df:

```
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ l1    │ l2    │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 2     │
│ 2   │ 3     │ 4     │
```

I tried unstack approach `unstack(df,  "col1", "col2")` but I got `ArgumentError: No key column found`. I understood that without key unstack is not possible. How to transform the above df to expected df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataFrames.jl requires you to specify keys for rows to allow to perform matching them by these keys:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(col1=["l1", "l2", "l1", "l2"], col2=1:4, rowkey=[1,1,2,2])
4×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ col1   │ col2  │ rowkey │
│     │ String │ Int64 │ Int64  │
├─────┼────────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ l1     │ 1     │ 1      │
│ 2   │ l2     │ 2     │ 1      │
│ 3   │ l1     │ 3     │ 2      │
│ 4   │ l2     │ 4     │ 2      │

julia> unstack(df, "col1", "col2")
2×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ rowkey │ l1     │ l2     │
│     │ Int64  │ Int64? │ Int64? │
├─────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │ 1      │ 2      │
│ 2   │ 2      │ 3      │ 4      │
```

Why? Imagine your data looks like this:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(col1=["l1", "l2", "l1", "l2","l1"], col2=1:5, rowkey=[1,1,3,3,2])
5×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ col1   │ col2  │ rowkey │
│     │ String │ Int64 │ Int64  │
├─────┼────────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ l1     │ 1     │ 1      │
│ 2   │ l2     │ 2     │ 1      │
│ 3   │ l1     │ 3     │ 3      │
│ 4   │ l2     │ 4     │ 3      │
│ 5   │ l1     │ 5     │ 2      │

julia> unstack(df, "col1", "col2")
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ rowkey │ l1     │ l2      │
│     │ Int64  │ Int64? │ Int64?  │
├─────┼────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │ 1      │ 2       │
│ 2   │ 2      │ 5      │ missing │
│ 3   │ 3      │ 3      │ 4       │
```

without `:rowkey` it would be not possible to tell that you actually want the second row in `:l2` to hold a missing value.

This is how `unstack` works as it is a general function, so it uses row keys to perform matching. If you want something that assumes:

- all groups are in the same orders
- all groups have the same lengths

write this:

```
julia> DataFrame([first(sdf.col1) => sdf.col2 for sdf in groupby(df, :col1)])
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ l1    │ l2    │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 2     │
│ 2   │ 3     │ 4     │
```

or a bit more general pattern

```
julia> DataFrame([key.col1 => sdf.col2 for (key, sdf) in pairs(groupby(df, :col1))])
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ l1    │ l2    │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 2     │
│ 2   │ 3     │ 4     │
```

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks for the answer.